# raspberry pi fail to fetch the update and upgrade

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am using raspberry pi zero and raspbian buster os. I was trying to install samba on it, but it failed to fetch the packages. following is the terminal log,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install samba -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  attr libcephfs2 libgpgme11 python-dnspython python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-tdb samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
Suggested packages:
  bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony smbldap-tools ufw winbind heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr libcephfs2 libgpgme11 python-dnspython python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-tdb samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,379 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python-dnspython all 1.16.0-1+deb10u1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python-ldb armhf 2:1.5.1+really1.4.6-3+deb10u1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python-tdb armhf 1.3.16-2+b1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python-samba armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:5 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-common all 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:6 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-common-bin armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:7 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf tdb-tools armhf 1.3.16-2+b1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
0% [Waiting for headers]^C
```

And later i was trying to run sudo apt upgrade install, it was also failing to fetch the update. here is the log,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek ghostscript git git-man libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libde265-0 libgs9 libgs9-common libmariadb3 libopenexr23
  libpam-systemd libpcre2-16-0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-posix0 libsystemd0 libtiff5 libudev1 libudisks2-0 mariadb-common python-cryptography python-werkzeug python3-cryptography python3-werkzeug systemd
  systemd-sysv tzdata udev udisks2 wireless-regdb xserver-common xserver-xorg-core
37 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 89.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 100 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf xserver-common all 2:1.20.4-1+rpt4+deb10u9 [2,236 kB]
Err:2 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf systemd-sysv armhf 241-7~deb10u9+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpam-systemd armhf 241-7~deb10u9+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libsystemd0 armhf 241-7~deb10u9+rpi1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]
```

1. I am able to ping the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and ping 8.8.8.8.
2. I confirm internet connection is also working

Comment: That .in mirror is broken (has been for more than a month). Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to not use it.

Comment: @Dougie Perhaps make that the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian is broken (has been for more than amonth now).

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to change it to a working mirror.

There's a list of mirrors at http://raspbian.com/RaspbianMirrors